# Parallel.ForEach duplicating data

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a strange situation, look:

```
public List<Car> GetCars(List<Entity> entities)
{
    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

    Parallel.ForEach(entities, entity =>
    {
        var car = ConvertToCar(entity);

        lock(cars)
        {
            cars.Add(car);
        }
    });
}
```

When I look into `cars` list AFTER `Parallel.ForEach` over 4 different `entities`, I got 4 identical cars. IF I put a breakpoint inside `Parallel.ForEach`, after 4 iterations (4 different `entities`), I got now, 4 different cars. So, why? What am I missing?

**EDIT AND SOLUTION**

Do you know when you lose all day because of something in front of you? Thank you @juharr. This code, is a legacy code, and Inside the method ConvertToCar, I didn't saw that:

```
public Car ConvertToCar(Entity entity)
{
    newCar = new Car();
    newCar.Id = entity.id;
    newCar.Color = entity.color;
    [...]

    return newCar;
}
```

Look to `newCar`, yes the in the legacy code, the new car is a global variable. It's that the problem. When I change to `var newCar = new Car();` everything is Ok!

Comment: Can you show us the code for `ConvertToCar`.

Comment: This code shouldnt compile, because function does not return anything. Can you pls update code?

Comment: Please share `ConvertToCar` code. May I suggest you to use a different `object` as `mutex` object lock? for example `var padLock = new object()` instead of `cars`.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad There's no problem with locking on `cars`.  It will always have the same object (during the period of time that's relevant) and is never exposed to any other contexts (higher or lower) that could lock on it.  It'd be better to structure the code in such a way that you didn't need the lock at all, but as it is, it's certainly not a problematic way to do so.